# set cron job for every 45 day to execute my php script using cron?

Tags: cron, crontrigger, cron-task

I need to run my cron after every 45 days in single line of shell terminal.
Please provide some solution for the same

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> ***    *    */45    *    *  /temp/command.sh**

It works in linux, but it can't be accepted by hp unix.

There is another choice: run below command every day:

> **[ $((  ($(date +%s)/86400) % 45  )) -eq 0 ] && /temp/command.sh**